# JSon Object to String Array android

Tags: android, arrays, json, string, list

I'm reading an array from a URL. All array contents are converted into a JSon object. Now I'm stuck here. Don't know how to separate each value from the Json Object. Please help!
My object has this data:
`jObj = {"success":1,"data":[{"ItemName":"Item1","ItemCode":"it1"},{"ItemName":"Item2","ItemCode":"it2"}]}`

Now how do I separate the data items ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a new class called Item so you can store information about items as objects, then simply iterate over JSONArray "data" and you are good to go, see the example:

```
int success = jObj.getInt("success");

List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
for (int i = 0; i < jObj.getJSONArray("data").length; i++)
{
    JSONObject current_object = jObj.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i);
    Item item = new Item(current_object.getString("ItemName"), current_object.getString("ItemCode"));
    items.add(item);
}

public Item
{
    String item_name;
    String item_code;

    public Item(item_name, item_code)
    {
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.item_code = item_code;
    }

    //  Place for setters and getters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string containing json you can parse it into a [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) like so:

```
try
{
    JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(myJsonString);
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
    // myJsonString is malformed / does not represent a json object 
}
```

You can call myJsonObject's methods as [defined here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) to get the values.

For example with the json string:

{ "name" : "Pring" }

```
String nameString = myJsonObject.getString("name");
```

nameString would be "Pring"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using [GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). This library provides methods to convert the json string to java objects. You have a brief tutorial [here](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java.jsp).